# Trackpad accidentally reloading websites

Tags: trackpad, magic-trackpad

I just upgraded to the new MacBook Pro, and thus now have a trackpad the size of Rhode Island. While typing I often rest/touch my palm on the edge of the trackpad.

Every now and then some combination of this will reload a website (loosing what I was in the middle of typing), and it's super annoying. I've looked through the Trackpad Preferences and not sure which to reload.

Halp!

Comment: Have you tried turning off "tap to click"? That way the only way to click will be to actually give the trackpad some force to cause a click, instead of being able to just tap it.

Comment: Thanks @JBallin, I've already had that disabled. I think it has something to do with a gesture possibly - where the edge of my palm hits the trackpad and is moving white typing?

Comment: I just re-read your question and realized I understood it incorrectly. Are you possibly swiping to one of the sides (2/3 fingers) causing your browser to go back/forward?

Comment: maybe you could try disabling "Swipe between pages" at the top of "More Gestures"?

Comment: Ah damn - changed this last night and thought it was it.... but it just happened again.